# Fluentmigrator Firebird migration rolls back automatically

Tags: firebird, fluent-migrator

I am just experimenting with fluentmigrator and after creating the first migration, it is automatically rolled back. The VersionInfo table is created. Here is the output I get after executing the command:

```
migrate.exe -a "Migrations.dll" --db Firebird -c " ... " -o --of="D:\log.sql" -t=migrate:up
```

the output I get in the console is:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
=============================== FluentMigrator ================================
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Source Code:
    http://github.com/schambers/fluentmigrator
Ask For Help:
    http://groups.google.com/group/fluentmigrator-google-group
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
201312020001: CreateUsersTable migrating
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[+] CreateTable Users
[+] Committing and Retaining Transaction
[+] Committing and Retaining Transaction
[+] Committing and Retaining Transaction
[+] 201312020001: CreateUsersTable migrated
[+] Undoing 3 transaction(s)
[+] Undoing transaction 3
[+] Undoing transaction 2
[+] Undoing transaction 1
[+] Task completed.
```

Here is the log file:

```
/* 201312020001: CreateUsersTable migrating ================================== */

/* CreateTable Users*/
CREATE TABLE "Users" ("UserId" INTEGER NOT NULL, "Name" VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, "PhoneNumber" VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL)
/* Committing and Retaining Transaction */
/* Committing and Retaining Transaction */

INSERT INTO "VersionInfo" ("Version", "AppliedOn") VALUES (201312020001, '2013-12-02 11:28:14')
/* Committing and Retaining Transaction */
/* 201312020001: CreateUsersTable migrated */

/* Undoing 3 transaction(s) */
/* Undoing transaction 3 */
DELETE FROM "VersionInfo" WHERE "Version" = 201312020001 AND "AppliedOn" = '2013-12-02 11:28:14'
/* Undoing transaction 2 */
/* Undoing transaction 1 */
DROP TABLE "Users"
/* Task completed. */
```

I have no ideea why is acting like this. Can anyone help me?

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like this bug: https://github.com/schambers/fluentmigrator/pull/405 : "The Firebird processor had a bug which reverted successfull migrations when dispose on the processor is called at the end of a migration."

Comment: Yes, but from I understand the bug is fixed and I am using the latest version.

Comment: As far as I can tell it hasn't been accepted into master yet.

Comment: Do I have some options then?

Comment: Yes, clone it, include the change and recompile.

Comment: Thanks Mark! I've run the migrate command directly from code and it seems ok.